# Does robinson arithmetic satisfy modal logic's "axiom 4"?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Does Robinson arithmetic prove the theorem "if sigma is provable then 'sigma is provable' is provable' for a fixed sentence sigma?

It's clear to me that you can get a primitive recursive function f from (proofs of sigma) to (proofs of "there is a proof of sigma").  Q can represent f, but can it actually prove that f has this property?

If not, then how do you get Godel's second incompleteness theorem for Q?

Answer (score 2):

This is the third *Hilbert-Bernays-Löb derivability condition*.

My source (Mendelson, Introduction to Mathematical Logic) just asserts it and notes that it "requires a careful and difficult proof". The impression I get is that this careful and difficult proof is indeed claimed to be doable in System Q, but that is not stated in so many words.

Mendelson refers to Boolos, *The Logic of Provability* (1993), ch. 2, and Shoenfield, *Mathematical Logic* (1967), pp. 211-213 -- neither of which I have.

*Edit:* [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4661/14366) to an earlier question claims that Q itself *cannot* verify the HBL conditions.

Comment: It's would seem amazing for $Q$ to be able to prove something like this, since $Q$ does not have induction, and one would seem to want to prove such a thing by induction on the size of the assumed proof.

Comment: @JDH: Good point.

Comment: I was interested in this a few months ago and looked into it some. As far as I can tell, the common belief is that $Q$ is not able to prove the derivability conditions, but at the same time I was not able to find an actual proof in print that $Q$ does not prove them. However, there are published proofs that the conclusion of the second incompleteness theorem holds for $Q$, and these proofs simply avoid the derivability conditions altogether.

Comment: Oh I see.  Q can't prove Con(Q) for the same reason it can't prove the derivability condition:  because it's so weak that it can't prove much of anything.  It probably can't even prove that the various ways of saying Con(Q) are equivalent.