# How much arithmetic is required to formalize quantifier elimination in Presburger arithmetic?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, reverse-math, quantifier-elimination, presburger-arithmetic

As we know, [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) can be proved decidable by demonstrating that it admits quantifier elimination, i.e. that there is an algorithm that reduces any sentence in the language to some equivalent quantifier-free sentence (which in turn can be decided). As a consequence, Presburger arithmetic is consistent, because it can easily be computed that 0 = 1 is not a theorem.

I am wondering how much first-order arithmetic is required to prove Presburger arithmetic admits quantifier elimination. We know [Robinson's Q is not strong enough to prove Con(Presburger)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648/can-robinsons-q-prove-presburger-arithmetic-consistent); how much more is required?